# Intuitive explanation of the integral formula of Inverse Laplace Transform

Tags: fourier-transform, laplace-transform, signal-processing, inverse-laplace

Let $F(s) = \mathcal{L}(f(t))$ be the Laplace transform of $f(t)$. Then, the inverse Laplace transform is given by a [path integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Laplace_transform)
$$
f(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \lim_{\omega\rightarrow\infty} \int_{\sigma - i \omega}^{\sigma+i\omega} e^{st} F(s) ds
$$
where $\sigma$ is chosen to be greater than the real parts of all singularities of $F(s)$.

As I understand, the constant $\sigma$ can be chosen arbitrarily as far as it satisfies the above condition so that $F(s)$ remains bounded on the line $\Re(s)=\sigma$. Then, how is it that one will end with a unique result by solving this integral for different values of $\sigma$?

Comment: $F(\sigma+i\omega)$ is the Fourier transform of $f(t)e^{-\sigma t}$, its inverse Fourier transform times $e^{\sigma t}$ equals $f$ (though depending on $f$ there may be a lot of convergence problems so equal is in broad sense)

Comment: Not clear. Can you elaborate a little?